# Metaprogramming trick to sort out private functions

Tags: c++, c++11, metaprogramming

This is a question regarding compile-time introspection in C++

Is there a known trick to detect that a matching function is actually private and thus can't be invoked? My intuitive guess is that this is *not possible* -- but maybe I'm wrong?

---

Explanation: using metaprogramming techniques (mostly based on the SFINAE mechanism), it is possible to detect the presence of properties (nested types, members, functions with specific signature) in a type given as template parameter (i.e. we know this type exists, but we don't know anything further about that type). Based on such introspection predicates, it is then possible to create specialised implementations, adapters, etc.

Now the specific twist is that such a predicate might match a private member of a class. When we subsequently generate code based on the result of that (false) match, the compilation fails, since we're actually not allowed to access that member. Thus a technique to sort out such false matches would be nice...

Comment: Violating access controls do cause substitution failures in C++11.

Comment: situation is confusing, possibly due to compiler support. When compiling on GCC 4.7, `std::is_copy_assignable<MyType>`  raises an error "operator= is private .... within this context".   The incriminating expression is in type_traits, 1049 (__is_assignable_helper): `decltype(declval<MyType&>() = declval<MyType const&>(), __one())`

Answer (score 6):

Ok, I never use it. It's just an idea.

So, to **detect if function exists**, we need something like this:

```
#include <iostream>

#define DEFINE_METHOD_CHECKER(RETURN_TYPE, METHOD_NAME, PARAMETERS)     \
template<typename T>                                                    \
struct Is ## METHOD_NAME ## MemberFunctionExists                        \
{                                                                       \
private:                                                                \
    typedef char True;                                                  \
    typedef char (&False)[2];                                           \
    template<typename U, RETURN_TYPE (U::*)PARAMETERS = &U::METHOD_NAME>\
    struct Checker                                                      \
    {                                                                   \
        typedef True Type;                                              \
    };                                                                  \
    template<typename U>                                                \
    static typename Checker<U>::Type Tester(const U*);                  \
    static False Tester(...);                                           \
public:                                                                 \
    enum { value = (sizeof(Tester(static_cast<const T*>(0))) == sizeof(True)) }; \
}

// IsMethodMemberFunctionExists<T>::value
DEFINE_METHOD_CHECKER(int, Method, (bool));
// IsTestMemberFunctionExists<T>::value
DEFINE_METHOD_CHECKER(int*, Test, (int&, char));

class Exists
{
public:
    int Method(bool);
    int* Test(int&, char);
};

class NotExists
{
};

int main()
{
   std::cout << IsMethodMemberFunctionExists<Exists>::value << std::endl;
    std::cout << IsTestMemberFunctionExists<Exists>::value << std::endl;

    std::cout << IsMethodMemberFunctionExists<NotExists>::value << std::endl;
    std::cout << IsTestMemberFunctionExists<NotExists>::value << std::endl;
}


Output:
1
1
0
0
```

[Live](http://rextester.com/PRWSP38909)

Good. If I will comment `public:` - functions will be private and our detector will print `0` - such a member function does not exists (*"Violating access controls do cause substitution failures in C++11."* as @T.C. said):

```
class Exists
{
//public:
    int Method(bool);
    int* Test(int&, char);
};

Output:
0
0
0
0
```

[Live](http://rextester.com/FSLD38847)

Now, to detect, **if given function is private**, we will make it *public* via abstract class. In a nutshell:

```
struct ITest
{
    virtual void foo() = 0;
};

class Test : ITest
{
    // foo() is private AND it's override Itest::foo() !
    void foo();
}

// std::is_abstract<Test>() yields false !
```

### So, all together

```
#define DEFINE_PRIVATE_METHOD_CHECKER(RETURN_TYPE, METHOD_NAME, PARAMETERS) \
DEFINE_METHOD_CHECKER(RETURN_TYPE, METHOD_NAME, PARAMETERS); \
template<typename T> \
struct IsPrivate ## METHOD_NAME ## MemberFunctionExists \
{ \
public: \
    struct IOverrideTest \
    { \
        virtual RETURN_TYPE METHOD_NAME PARAMETERS = 0; \
    }; \
    \
    class OverrideTest : T, IOverrideTest {}; \
    \
public: \
    enum { value = !IsMethodMemberFunctionExists<T>::value && !std::is_abstract<OverrideTest>::value }; \
}

// IsPrivateMethodMemberFunctionExists<T>::value
DEFINE_PRIVATE_METHOD_CHECKER(int, Method, (bool));

#include <iostream>

class PrivateExists
{
private:
    int Method(bool);
    int* Test(int&, char);
};

class NotExists
{
};

int main()
{   
    std::cout << IsPrivateMethodMemberFunctionExists<PrivateExists>::value << std::endl;
    std::cout << IsMethodMemberFunctionExists<PrivateExists>::value << std::endl;

    //std::cout << IsPrivateMethodMemberFunctionExists<NotExists>::value << std::endl;
    //std::cout << IsMethodMemberFunctionExists<NotExists>::value << std::endl;
}
```

The code looks legit, BUT:

[Clang Live](http://rextester.com/WSPQ34393) will produce expected output:

```
1
0
```

[gcc Live](http://rextester.com/QIFF66186):

```
0
0
```

[VC++ Live](http://rextester.com/RYPG97950) will **not** compile it.

Hmmm..
The things become strange with next code uncomented:

```
int main()
{   
    std::cout << IsPrivateMethodMemberFunctionExists<PrivateExists>::value << std::endl;
    std::cout << IsMethodMemberFunctionExists<PrivateExists>::value << std::endl;

    std::cout << IsPrivateMethodMemberFunctionExists<NotExists>::value << std::endl;
    std::cout << IsMethodMemberFunctionExists<NotExists>::value << std::endl;
}
```

[Clang Live](http://rextester.com/HPYZ28770):

```
1
0
1
0
```

[gcc Live](http://rextester.com/TVEW82883)

```
0
0
0
0
```

**Update:** I had a mistake about overriding:

```
class Exists
{
    void foo();
};

struct ITest
{
    virtual void foo() = 0;
};

class TestExists : Exists, ITest
{
};
```

`TestExists` will not override `foo()`, so it's still abstract. The solution is wrong. Bu compilers results are interesting...

Comment: The difference is... rather interesting. It seems to be caused by the nested class: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f418a969d55ec68f -- it does look quite like a bug.

Comment: TestExists needs a `using Exists::foo`.

Comment: @dascandy, I can't use using-declaration because, actually, I don't know, If function exists (in generic code).. and this function is private